# Vector Addition Cuda program on cluster giving many errors

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I am trying to run a Cuda vector addition program on Tesla K20 server and I'm getting a lot of errors. I'm submitting the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cuda_utils.h"
#include "timer.h"
/*
* **CUDA KERNEL** 
* 
* Compute the sum of two vectors 
*   C[i] = A[i] + B[i]
* 
*/
__global__ void vecAdd(float* a, float* b, float* c) {

/* Calculate index for this thread */
  int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

 /* Compute the element of C */
 c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
 }

 void compute_vec_add(int N, float *a, float* b, float *c);

/*
* 
* Host code to drive the CUDA Kernel
* 
*/
int main() {

float *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;
float *h_a, *h_b, *h_c, *h_temp;
int i;
int N = 1024 * 1024 * 512;

struct stopwatch_t* timer = NULL;
long double t_pcie_htd, t_pcie_dth, t_kernel, t_cpu;

/* Setup timers */
stopwatch_init();
timer = stopwatch_create();

/*
Create the vectors
*/
h_a = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
h_b = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
h_c = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * N);

/*
 Set the initial values of h_a, h_b, and h_c
 */
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
h_a[i] = (float) (rand() % 100) / 10.0;
h_b[i] = (float) (rand() % 100) / 10.0;
h_c[i] = 0.0;
}

/*
Allocate space on the GPU
*/
CUDA_CHECK_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&d_a, sizeof(float) * N));
CUDA_CHECK_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&d_b, sizeof(float) * N));
CUDA_CHECK_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&d_c, sizeof(float) * N));

/*
Copy d_a and d_b from CPU to GPU
*/
stopwatch_start(timer);
CUDA_CHECK_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, sizeof(float) * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
CUDA_CHECK_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, sizeof(float) * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
t_pcie_htd = stopwatch_stop(timer);
fprintf(stderr, "Time to transfer data from host to device: %Lg secs\n",t_pcie_htd);

/*
Run N/256 blocks of 256 threads each
*/
dim3 GS(N / 256, 1, 1);
dim3 BS(256, 1, 1);

stopwatch_start(timer);
vecAdd<<<GS, BS>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c);
cudaThreadSynchronize();
t_kernel = stopwatch_stop(timer);
fprintf(stderr, "Time to execute GPU kernel: %Lg secs\n", t_kernel);

/*
Copy d_cfrom GPU to CPU
*/
stopwatch_start(timer);
CUDA_CHECK_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(h_c, d_c, sizeof(float) * N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
t_pcie_dth = stopwatch_stop(timer);
fprintf(stderr, "Time to transfer data from device to host: %Lg secs\n",t_pcie_dth);

/* 
 Double check errors
 */
h_temp = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
stopwatch_start(timer);
compute_vec_add(N, h_a, h_b, h_temp);
t_cpu = stopwatch_stop(timer);
fprintf(stderr, "Time to execute CPU program: %Lg secs\n", t_cpu);

int cnt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
if (abs(h_temp[i] - h_c[i]) > 1e-5)
  cnt++;
}
fprintf(stderr, "number of errors: %d out of %d\n", cnt, N);

/*
 Free the device memory
*/
cudaFree(d_a);
cudaFree(d_b);
cudaFree(d_c);

/*
 Free the host memory
*/
free(h_a);
free(h_b);
free(h_c);

/* 
 Free timer 
*/
stopwatch_destroy(timer);

if (cnt == 0) {
printf("\n\nSuccess\n");
}
}
```

Now for this code that I'm running I get a huge list of errors. I have timer.c and cuda_utils.h in the same directory.
For compiling,

```
nvcc vecAdd.cu timer.c -o vecAdd
```

And then the errors I get are:

```
/tmp/tmpxft_000014db_00000000-17_vecAdd.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_000014db_00000000-4_vecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `stopwatch_init()'
tmpxft_000014db_00000000-4_vecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `stopwatch_create()'
tmpxft_000014db_00000000-4_vecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x278): undefined reference to `stopwatch_start(stopwatch_t*)'
tmpxft_000014db_00000000-4_vecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2ff): undefined reference to `stopwatch_stop(stopwatch_t*)'
tmpxft_000014db_00000000-4_vecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x380): undefined reference to `stopwatch_start(stopwatch_t*)'
tmpxft_000014db_00000000-4_vecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x3dc): undefined reference to `stopwatch_stop(stopwatch_t*)'
tmpxft_000014db_00000000-4_vecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x416): undefined reference to `stopwatch_start(stopwatch_t*)'
tmpxft_000014db_00000000-4_vecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x45e): undefined reference to `stopwatch_stop(stopwatch_t*)'
tmpxft_000014db_00000000-4_vecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x4b0): undefined reference to `stopwatch_start(stopwatch_t*)'
tmpxft_000014db_00000000-4_vecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x4de): undefined reference to `stopwatch_stop(stopwatch_t*)'
tmpxft_000014db_00000000-4_vecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x61f): undefined reference to `stopwatch_destroy(stopwatch_t*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can somebody throw some light on why these errors are coming. Moreover I'm a beginner in Cuda programming.
My guess is it has something to with linking.

Comment: Your compiler doesnt know what `stopwatch_init()` is. Where is that defined?

Comment: Its defined in timer.c that I'm using for compiling.

Comment: Well, something mus be wrong with that, because the compiler clearly says "undefined"

Comment: Shouldn't the compilation command be different, I mean `vecAdd.cu` **after** `timer.c`?

Comment: CUDA is not C !

Answer (score 1):

`nvcc` interprets `.cu` code as C++ code and this will cause conflicts with symbol names. The solution is to enclose `#include "timer.h"` with `extern "C" {}` in `vecAdd.cu`.

> The problem is that if the .cu files include C functions from another .c file, lets say function.c, those functions will be interpreted as C++ functions, which in turn **sets special symbol names for those functions**. Later, when compiling function.c, those functions will be compiled with normal symbol names. At the linking stage, since the symbol names from the .cu file do not match those of the compiled function.o file, you will get unresolved references. So you need to use the extern "C"{} syntax around headers including external C code functions.

(Quoted from [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/506228/compiling-c-and-cuda-code-problems-linking-cuda-code-and-c-code/))

---

**Verification**

Compiling `vecAdd.cu` provided in the question with `nvcc -c vecAdd.cu` and listing symbols with `nm vecAdd.o` prints following lines:

```
...
00000000000007cf t _Z10cudaLaunchIcE9cudaErrorPT_
00000000000007aa t _Z10cudaMallocIfE9cudaErrorPPT_m
                 U _Z14stopwatch_initv
                 U _Z14stopwatch_stopP11stopwatch_t
0000000000000016 T _Z15compute_vec_addiPfS_S_
                 U _Z15stopwatch_startP11stopwatch_t
                 U _Z16stopwatch_createv
                 U _Z17stopwatch_destroyP11stopwatch_t
0000000000000672 T _Z29__device_stub__Z6vecAddPfS_S_PfS_S_
0000000000000703 T _Z6vecAddPfS_S_
...
```

You can see that `stopwatch_init` became `_Z14stopwatch_iniv`, and so on.

Since there's no definition for `timer.c` and `timer.h`, I wrote a minimal code for them.

```
// timer.h
struct stopwatch_t { double t; };
void stopwatch_init();
struct stopwatch_t *stopwatch_create();
void stopwatch_start(struct stopwatch_t *timer);
long double stopwatch_stop(struct stopwatch_t *timer);
void stopwatch_destroy(struct stopwatch_t *timer);

// timer.c
void stopwatch_init() { }
struct stopwatch_t *stopwatch_create() { return 0; }
void stopwatch_start(struct stopwatch_t *timer) { }
long double stopwatch_stop(struct stopwatch_t *timer) { return 0; }
void stopwatch_destroy(struct stopwatch_t *timer) { }
```

With above code, `nvcc -c timer.c` and `nm timer.o` yields:

```
0000000000000007 T stopwatch_create
0000000000000029 T stopwatch_destroy
0000000000000000 T stopwatch_init
0000000000000012 T stopwatch_start
000000000000001d T stopwatch_stop
```

You can see that there's going to be symbol name conflicts for `timer.c` functions.

After modyfing `vecAdd.cu` to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cuda_utils.h"
extern "C" {
    #include "timer.h"
}
...
```

`nvcc -c vecAdd.cu` and `nm vecAdd.o` yields:

```
...
                 U __stack_chk_fail
                 U stderr
                 U stopwatch_create
                 U stopwatch_destroy
                 U stopwatch_init
                 U stopwatch_start
                 U stopwatch_stop
00000000000007cf t _Z10cudaLaunchIcE9cudaErrorPT_
00000000000007aa t _Z10cudaMallocIfE9cudaErrorPPT_m
...
```

You can see that there's no change in the symbol names for the C functions. In this case, the compile command in the question: `nvcc vecAdd.cu timer.c -o vecAdd` will work.

---

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comment by OP, `g++ -c timer.c` and `nvcc vecAdd.cu timer.o -o vecAdd` will also work since `g++` will by default treat `.c` files as C++ code.

`g++ -c timer.c` and `nm timer.o` prints:

```
0000000000000000 T _Z14stopwatch_initv
000000000000001d T _Z14stopwatch_stopP11stopwatch_t
0000000000000012 T _Z15stopwatch_startP11stopwatch_t
0000000000000007 T _Z16stopwatch_createv
0000000000000029 T _Z17stopwatch_destroyP11stopwatch_t
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it. There was a problem with the compilation of timer.c, I had used gcc instead of g++. It solved the problem.